# Unexplained errors when using "go get"

Tags: go

I'm using go 1.9 on OS X 10.12.6. I was attempting to "go get" github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter, and was presented with the following cryptic errors:

```
  % go get github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter   
# golang.org/x/sys/unix
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/dirent.go:68:17: undefined: direntReclen
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/dirent.go:74:14: undefined: direntIno
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/dirent.go:81:24: constant -1000000000 overflows uint64
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/dirent.go:81:41: undefined: Dirent
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/dirent.go:82:17: undefined: direntNamlen
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/flock.go:13:30: undefined: SYS_FCNTL
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/flock.go:16:42: undefined: Flock_t
code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix/flock.go:17:17: undefined: Syscall
```

I also attempted to go get with -u and -v, and while verbose mode provides some more information, none is really relevant to the errors seen here. Has anyone seen anything like this before?

Comment: Something is wrong with your checkout of the golang.org/x/sys/unix package. Clean that out first.

Comment: Ok, I tried deleting the offending package and it might be worse than before! I don't get the same error, now I get this:

  % go get github.com/maxbrunsfeld/counterfeiter
package golang.org/x/sys/unix: cannot find package "golang.org/x/sys/unix" in any of:
 /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.9/libexec/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix (from $GOROOT)
 /Users/cbny/code/go/src/golang.org/x/sys/unix (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Did you run `go get golang.org/x/sys/unix`?

Comment: Thanks Jim, I figured it out. Had to remove the entire golang.org package before I did the go get on golang.org/x/sys/unix

Answer (score 0):

Solved the same issue with just `GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go get ...`